# Make node package injectable

Tags: node.js, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

How to make node package (class from node_modules) injectable?

I use `inversify` in my app and I want to bind `Validator.ts` class to my container. How can I do it?

`const container = new Container();
container.bind<Validator>(Validator).toSelf();`

Is not enough cause I got:

`Error: Missing required @injectable annotation in: Validator.`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy:

`decorate(injectable(), Validator);`

or

`container.bind<Validator>(Validator).toConstantValue(new Validator());`

[This post](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/517) helped me out.